# How can I get the file path for a file I only know the name of? C#

Tags: c#

So I'm making a Tic Tac Toe application and have created a Text file linked to the program to hold the following information:

- the name
- the time took to win
- the difficulty

I know the timer is redundant for a quick game like Tic Tac Toe but I'll use it in the future for other programs.

- My question is how can I find the full path of the file while only knowing the name of the file?

I want to do this using the program so it can be transferred to any computer and still be able to access the file without the user having to input it.

The code I've tried is:

```
string file_name = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Tic Tac Toe\\HighScores.txt");
```

But this just looks in the Debug folder, where the file isn't located. The application is entirely a console application.

Comment: So you want to search whole hard disk?

Comment: Many files can have the same name, so you will have to know where to look.

Comment: Have you considered that the "CurrentDirectory" will be wherever the program is being run? Thus, if you copied the file to the root of a drive, then it may look there?

Comment: 1. Preferably I don't want to search the whole hard disk. 2. I was thinking using a partial directory e.g. Tic Tac Toe\Tic Tac Toe\HighScores.txt.3. I found the code on that and realised it when I ran it, I'm not too sure about moving the file around incase I break anything, and this program has took a hell of a lot of time as it is.

Comment: You, as the programmer, have to decide where your game should save (and thus expect to find) that file. For example, `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Tic Tac Toe", "HighScores.txt")`.

Comment: Well, why *isn't* the file in the `Debug` directory? That's where the whole application bundle should be when debugging, really. If you want the file to be easily transferrable along with your application, there isn't really a better way (though there's a lot of good reasons not to allow write access to your application bundle, it's not a big deal for a toy like this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to dedicate the file in a fixed sub directory:

\TicTacToe.exe
\settings\settings.cfg

So the path is dependent of your executable file.

You'll fetch the directory by calling `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

You can set a desired directory by setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

A common way to handle this case is the one described above.

Another would be to use user specifiy directories like the %appdata% path and create a dedicated directory there.

%appdata%\TicTacToe\settings.cfg

Everytime your application starts it should lookup the folder %appdata%\TicTacToe\

If it is present, your application has been executed with this user.
If not, just create a new one, so we know it's the first run.

You can get the %appdata% path by calling

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Example of what i would have done

```
private void setUp(){
string filename = "settings.cfg";
string dir = "TicTacToe";
string appdata =Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string fullpath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(appdata,dir),filename);

//check if file exists, more accurate than just looking for the folder
if(File.Exists(fullpath )){
//read the file and process its content
}else{
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(appdata,dir)); // will do nothing if directory exists, but then we have a bug: no file, but directory available
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fullpath))
            {
                Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
                // Add some information to the file.
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }
 }
 }
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: so what would be in the config file? the highscoring data?

Comment: All data that has to be saved: the name,
the time took to win,
the difficulty

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a configuration file for your application and store the directory name in there.

An old example from MS, but should still be applicable...

[How to store and retrieve custom information from an application configuration file by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815786)

Comment: I'm sorry... but how do I do that? I've had to teach myself C# and only been doing it for about 14 weeks

Comment: Thankfully configuration files is a feature Visual Studio provides lots of direct support for through its project settings. It generates a namespace you can use in your code, based on the project name.